# JDBC select and update in one request

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Here is a table in oracle db:

```sql
ID varchar2() primary key, 
STATUS varchar2(),
....
```

I need to select rows with status 'DELAYED' and in same time set status 'PROGRESS'.

Any way to do it using JDBC?

Comment: you want to update rows with status as `DELAYED` to `PROGRESS` ?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: yes. oracle v19c

Comment: I'm no Oracle expert but I'd assume you should be able to use an `UPDATE ... RETURNING...`

Comment: Why do you need to do that in a single statement?

Comment: Because that table is a table with some delayed work that need to processed by java code.
I have some threads that works with that table. And I need to mark rows that already in process to exclude reprocessing in another threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you can create auxiliary packages

You can use the PL/SQL `UPDATE .. RETURNING` syntax. I think the `BULK COLLECT INTO` semantics still can't be used with jdbc directly, so you have to use an anonymous PL/SQL block and some tricks, instead:

```sql
-- An auxiliary package is needed to declare the type.
create or replace package p as 
  type t is table of my_table%rowtype;
end p;
/

declare
  r p.t;
  c sys_refcursor;
begin
  update my_table
  set status = 'PROGRESS'
  where status = 'DELAYED'
  returning id, status, ...
  bulk collect into r;

  -- The package is needed for this syntax, which cannot yet work on types
  -- declared in anonymous blocks:
  open c for select * from table(r);
  dbms_sql.return_result(c);
end;
/
```

And then fetch the result. Unfortunately, that's a bit painful as can be seen in this blog post:
https://blog.jooq.org/how-i-incorrectly-fetched-jdbc-resultsets-again/

(in particular, depending on the ojdbc version, there's a bug when fetching `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` results)

```sql
// Alternatively, use a prepared statement if needed
try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {

    fetchLoop:
    for (int i = 0, updateCount = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        boolean result = (i == 0)
            ? s.execute(
                """
                declare
                  r p.t;
                  c sys_refcursor;
                begin
                  ...
                end;
                """)
            : s.getMoreResults();

        if (result)
            try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
                // Consume result set
            }
        else if ((updateCount = s.getUpdateCount()) != -1)
            System.out.println("Update Count: " + updateCount);
        else
            break fetchLoop;
    }
}
```

You can also fetch the `SYS_REFCURSOR` value as an `OUT` parameter of a `CallableStatement`

#### If you cannot create packages

If you cannot create a package, then you could serialise individual columns using `DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE` etc, but that's even more involved. It would look roughly like this:

```sql
declare
  o0 dbms_sql.number_table;
  o1 dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
  -- repeat for all columns
  c0 sys_refcursor;
  c1 sys_refcursor;
  -- repeat for all columns
begin
  update my_table
  set status = 'PROGRESS'
  where status = 'DELAYED'
  returning id, status, ...
  bulk collect into o0, o1;
  -- Optional rowcount if you need that, as an OUT parameter
  ? := sql%rowcount;
  open c0 for select * from table(o0);
  open c1 for select * from table(o1);
  -- These can also be fetched as OUT parameters if you want
  ? := c0;
  ? := c1;
end;
```

This probably causes more network traffic and requires re-assembling multiple per-column result sets into a single one, so if you can, I recommend the package approach.

This is what [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) is doing behind the scenes when you run an `UPDATE .. RETURNING` statement.

Comment: I think Im doing something wrong. Code since declare not working in oracle sql developer. begin mark as red.
Package p compiled

Comment: @DeimontM: Add `/` in SQL developer after each statement

Answer (score 0):

As you can not do that in JDBC directly, You could use following code snippet to do so in 2 steps, I hope it help you:

Here we should use *jdbc:oracle* as the driver, and `update ... set ... where` syntax.

First you have to call **updateTable()** to change all *DELAYED* rows to *PROGRESS* and then call **getAllDelayedObjects()** to get all *DELAYED* rows as a *List*.

(Use your own *Entity Type* which you want to keep database results (in *getAllDelayedObjects()*) instead of *YourEntityClass* **OR** you could just print *resultSet* in console)

```
public class DataAccess {
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;

    public boolean updateTable() throws SQLException {
        openConnection();
        try (PreparedStatement statement=
                connection.prepareStatement("update yourTableName set STATUS=? where STATUS=?")
        ) {
            statement.setString(1, "DELAYED");
            statement.setString(2, "PROGRESS");
            
            if (statement.executeUpdate()>0) {
                closeConnection();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                closeConnection();
                return false;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }


    public List<YourEntityClass> getAllDelayedObjects() throws SQLException {
        openConnection();
        try (
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where STATUS=?")
        ) {
            
            statement.setString(2, "PROGRESS");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            List<YourEntityClass> entityObjects = new ArrayList<>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                YourDaType object = new YourDaType();
                entityObject.setId(resultSet.getInt("ID"));
                entityObject.setStatus(resultSet.getString("STATUS"));
                // and whatever more properties you have in the table

                entityObjects.add(object);
            }
            closeConnection();
            return entityObjects;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            closeConnection();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void openConnection() throws SQLException {
        String username = "yourUserNameForDB";
        String pass = "yourPasswordForDB";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle://yourDBdomain:yourDBport/yourDataBaseName", username, pass);
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
        this.connection.close();
    }
}
```